# Underlying kafka version in kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a topic from which I need to consume and process data and I am using kafka-python package to do so.

I am facing a lot of issues related to rebalancing, slow data consumption across a few partitions, and want to confirm if it because of any compatibility issues.

So, how can I check what is the underlying Kafka version used in kafka-python so that I can eliminate the possibility

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

kafka-python is a native Python library, so there is no "Kafka version" such as the native Java library it depends on.

The native binary Kafka TCP protocol has no discernible version

If you were to use confluent kafka Python library, then that would depend on a version of librdkafka C bindings